# window.open same domain permission denied to access property 'document'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to access document on a new window, within the same domain, however I get that permission is denied. Why would this be?

```
function test(){
    var test1 = document.createElement('a'); 
    document.body.appendChild(test1); 
    test1.innerHTML = 'me'; 
    test1.onclick = function(){
        var wnd = window.open('../../../../../', 'wnd'); 
        setInterval(function(){
            wnd.document.write(1)
        }, 5000);
    }
};
```

Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: Are you doing this through a server eg: `localhost` or are you going through your file system eg: `file:\\blahblah\word\other\something.hmtl`?

Comment: are you testing on IE?

Comment: FireFox 26. It doesn't work on any browsers, though. If I console.log wnd, I can see details. Additionally, if I do addEventListener('load', ...), the load event is fired off at the correct time. console.log(event) will display the event and domains, however doing console.log(event.currentTarget) logs nothing and is blank (clicking the event in console will display it, though).

Comment: Hey, I deleted my post because I just tested what you have in FF, and it is working. Every five seconds, my page is updating with another "1". Granted, I just pasted it into a console.

Comment: Would it make a different if the window that is being opened is redirecting itself (all be it same domain, still)?